# How do I update a view's content when a UITableView is rearranged?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here's a run down of what I want to accomplish:

- Main `UIViewController` is a `UITableViewController`
- Tapping on a cell takes user to a new `UIViewController` where they can input text and save it
- User can preview all the text saved on another `UIViewController`
- When user re-arranges the table in the Main `UIViewController`, user can see the changes in the Preview

How can I change/move the text on the Preview `UIViewController` when the `UITableViewController` is re-arranged?

Any general approach, tips, tutorials, examples is much appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT, Here's my code:

Singleton .h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface MyInformation : NSObject
 {
     NSMutableArray * informationArray;
     NSMutableString * nameString;
     NSMutableString * jobString;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * informationArray;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString * nameString;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString * jobString;

 + (id)sharedInformation;

 @end
```

Singleton .m

```
 #import "MyInformation.h"

 @implementation MyInformation

 static MyInformation * _sharedMyInformation = nil;

 @synthesize informationArray = _informationArray;
 @synthesize nameString = _nameString;
 @synthesize jobString = _jobString;

 #pragma mark Singleton Methods

 + (id)sharedInformation
 {
     @synchronized(self)
     {
         if (_sharedMyInformation == nil)
         {
             _sharedMyInformation = [[self alloc] init];
         }   
     }
     return _sharedMyInformation;
 }

 - (id)init
 {
     if (self = [super init])
     {
         _nameString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
         _jobString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
         _informationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:_nameString, _jobString, nil];

     }
     return self;
 }

 @end
```

ViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
     {
         self.aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1136) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
         self.aTableView.delegate = self;
         self.aTableView.dataSource = self;
         [self.view addSubview:self.aTableView];

         self.editBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editButtonTapped)];
         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editBarButtonItem;
     }
 }

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     [self.aTableView reloadData];
 }

 - (void)editButtonTapped
 {
      if (self.editing)
      {
          [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
          [self.aTableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
          [self.aTableView reloadData];
          [self.editBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
          [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
       }
       else
       {
          [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
          [self.aTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
          [self.aTableView reloadData];
          [self.editBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
          [self.editBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
       }
   }

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
      return 2;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
      MyInformation * myInformation = [MyInformation sharedInformation];
      int count = [myInformation.informationArray count];

      if (section == 0)
      {
          return count;
      }
      else if (section == 1)
      {
          return 1;
      }

      return count;
  }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

     UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil)
      {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }

     MyInformation * myInformation = [MyInformation sharedInformation];

     if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
     {
         cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myInformation.nameString];
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
     }

     if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1)
     {
         cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myInformation.jobString];
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
     }

     if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
     {
         cell.textLabel.text = @"Preview";
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
     }

     return cell;
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

      if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
      {
         NameViewController * name = [[NameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameViewController" bundle:nil];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:name animated:YES];
      }

     if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1)
     {
         JobViewController * job = [[JobViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JobViewController" bundle:nil];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:job animated:YES];    
     }

     if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
     {
         PreviewViewController * preview = [[PreviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:preview animated:YES];
    }
 }


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
 {
     MyInformation * myInformation = [MyInformation sharedInformation];

     NSString * item = [myInformation.informationArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
     [myInformation.informationArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
     [myInformation.informationArray insertObject:item atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
 }

 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     if (indexPath.section == 0 )
     {
         return YES;
     }   
     else
     {
         return NO;  
     }
 }
 @end
```

EDIT 2:

I do not believe my array is getting updated.

Here's an example of my save code:

```
 - (IBAction)saveButtonTapped
 {
     MyInformation * myInformation = [MyInformation sharedInformation];

     if (_nameTextField.text == nil)
     {
         myInformation.nameString = @"";
     } 
     else
     {
         [myInformation.nameString setString:@""];
         [myInformation.nameString appendFormat:@"%@", _nameTextField.text];
     }

     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

In this log, the nameString does update to whatever text I type in and save.

But my informationArray always returns as ( "", "" )

EDIT 3 & 4:

Hard coding the strings in the singleton with set characters.

Now I can rearrange my table which is good.

Below is the updated code. The labels on the preview page will rearrange when I rearrange the table.

Here's that code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     MyInformation * myInformation = [MyInformation sharedInformation];

     _nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
     _nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 300, 44);
     _nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myInformation.informationArray objectAtIndex:0]];

     _jobLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
     _jobLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 44);
     _jobLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myInformation.informationArray objectAtIndex:1]];

     [self.view addSubview:_nameLabel];
     [self.view addSubview:_jobLabel];
 }
```

EDIT 5:

The only thing left to accomplish is how do I update the text in the strings in the singleton and in the UITableViewCells?

EDIT 6:

I solved the issue.  I had to change the strings in the Singleton to NSMutableStrings.  I modified my save button code to set the string to an empty value and the append it with the textfield text. After this it now works as expected!

Thank you for the help and suggestions!

Comment: Trying to find a general direction of how to approach this. Not sure how to go about it at the moment.

Comment: Ok, so, both the table and the preview views are on screen at the same time as each other and you want to update the preview for the cell at the top of the table view?

Comment: No, the main view is a table view. Tapping on a cell goes to a detail page to enter text.  The bottom cell will point to the preview page.  The user can rearrange the tableviewcells that lead to detailed views with the text.  I want the preview to stay updated with the table so it lists the text in the same order.

Comment: Each cell is like a block of text, with associated order information. And the preview always lists all of the blocks of text, in order. You simply want to store the text and order information together and then when the preview is displayed you can build the view. And you need the same data to order the table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have a backing `NSMutableArray`, but the answer should generalize to any data storage scheme.

1. Use [`tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3amoveRowAtIndexPath%3atoIndexPath%3a) to detect when the user reorders the first table and update the backing array by removing the object at `fromIndexPath.row` and inserting it at `toIndexPath.row`.  This makes sure that your backing models accurately reflect the changes the user just made in the UI.
2. When the user moves to the preview view, that view either needs to pull from the same shared data source (the one we modified in #1) or be given a copy of the just rearranged array.  The latter case is simpler and can be done by adding an `NSArray` property on the preview controller: `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *itemsToPreview`.  Then ensure that the preview controller uses that array instead of the original one.

[Apple's documentation on reordering table views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) is a good resource.

Comment: Right now I am using a singleton with an NSMutableArray that will hold all the information. Not having much luck so far. Stuck but can't find what I am missing. Will post code soon.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Your `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` code looks fine, so can you `NSLog` `myInformation` and ensure that the order changed?  If so, then what else makes you believe that you are stuck?

Comment: After I save the text in a detailed UIViewController and pop back to the main UIViewController a new row is added to section 0 of my table (and the new row has Preview as the text label).  This happens for when I save text from the original 2 cells. When I tap 'Done' after I edit the table and rearrange the rows they stay in their original place.

Comment: Is that because you are hardcoding what you think will be at each row (e.g., `if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)`)?  You should examine `myInformation` instead to determine what should appear at each row to keep the reordering intact.